# Como usar iReport com Oracle?

Tags: java, oracle, ireport

Estou tendo problemas para adicionar o **driver Oracle** no `iReport Designer`, tentei seguir alguns tutoriais, porém não obtive êxito. 
Então a minha dúvida é, como eu faço para adicionar e realizar as configurações necessárias para o driver Oracle?

Observação: tente seguir esses passos:

http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/connecting-ireport-oracle-datasource
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aWePwTz1knI

edit erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu geralmente faço assim:

> 1. Vou na opção **Ferramentas** na barra de menus;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> 2. Depois na opção **IReport** e na aba **Classpath**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> 3. Depois clico em adicionar Jars, ai você localiza o driver do oracle. Localizado e adicionado, clica em ok

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após isso, ao você tentar adicionar uma conexão com driver oracle, ele estará habilitado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aí você coloca os dados de conexão

Isso é o que eu faço

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: poderia me mostrar os dados de conexão também ? Estou tendo o erro: Exception
 
Message:
    java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

Comment: Os dados de conexão variam de empresa para empresa: é só você preencher de acordo com sua necessidade, por exemplo: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip-do-servidor:1521:nome-do-banco-ou-servico` No campo Endereço do Servidor (**Server Address**), você o coloca o ip do seu servidor, no **Database**, o nome do banco ou serviço, e finalmente o login e a senha   e clica em test ou save

Comment: verifique também seu tsname

Comment: Eu tentei fazer como você sugeriu, ainda não consegui, eu editei a pergunta e adicionei uma imagem para ilustrar o erro, se você puder olhar e me dar um novo "parecer" a respeito.

Comment: eu tentei simular o erro e consegui mudando alguma coisa, por exemplo, mudei a porta e deu esse mesmo erro, verifique com detalhe, o nome do banco, a porta, o servidor, enfim.

Comment: obrigado, funcionou !

Comment: Legal!, que bom que funcionou